# How would I complete number 2 on the following check list and/or just finish the program?

Tags: python, loops, data-structures, python-2.4, myro

Here's the problem I'm working on:

> Assume that the developers of Myro are developing a new black box
>   function called traveler(String str ) that moves a robot in a specific
>   direction (i.e., North, South, East, or West) for a specific number of
>   feet (e.g., 1 = one foot, 2 = two feet, etc.) The parameter of the
>   traveler( ) function is a String variable that expresses both the
>   direction and the distance. For example, traveler(E2) would move the
>   robot East for two feet while traveler(N6) would move the robot North
>   for six feet.
>
> Write a short segment of code that uses the black box traveler( )
>   function to move the robot from Point A to Point B in the grid shown
>   below.
>
> 1. Assign the parameters (e.g. N2, etc.) to a data structure.
> 2. Traverse the data structure with a loop that supplies the parameters to the traveler( ) function.

[image: Path to follow]

> The traveler(String str) function does not really exist.  Treat it as
>   if it did and simply write a short segment of code to accomplish the
>   task of moving the robot along the pattern given above.

Here's what I have:

```
    def main():
    go = [N2, W1, N3, E4, S1, W1, S1, E2]
    for g go:
        traveler(g)

main()
```

My question is how would finish this up?

Comment: http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/html/book011.html section 10.3 is traversing a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

traversing lists in python is generally done by using a [`for`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) loop

Example from python documentation:

```
>>> # Measure some strings:
... words = ['cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']
>>> for w in words:
...     print w, len(w)
...
cat 3
window 6
defenestrate 12
```

In the above example `len` is a built in function.  They are passing `w` to the `len` function.  This is very simliar to what you need to do with the `traveler` function.
Loop through every item in `go` list.  Pass that item to `traveler`

Comment: So Like this?:

 def main():
    go = [N2, W1, N3, E4, S1, W1, S1, E2]
    for g in range(len(go)):
        traveler(g)

main()

Comment: @TheProfessor  very close you have the correct idea but you can refactor to just be `for g in go`: traveler(g)`